# I want to download my Pdf File in server path in mvc please any one guide me... with code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, model-view-controller, view

what is the controller code.
how can i set the path of the server folder.

```
string path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Areas/CreatePaperSet/PdfPaperSet");
HttpContext.Response.TransmitFile(path);


WebClient client = new WebClient();
byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(path);
if (buffer != null)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=DownloadPaperSet.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
    Response.End();

}


pdfDoc.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my way to download file in folder and it worked.

You can create an Action with fileName as parameter.
In action you read file as byte[] and return File object.

```
public ActionResult Download(string fileName)
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/PdfPaperSet");
           
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path + @"\" + fileName);
            
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

In your cshtml file, pass fileName = "yourfile.pdf" as parameter.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download Your File", "Download", new { fileName = "yourfile.pdf" })
```

Beware of [Path Traversal Attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal) by adding some additional argument validation checks:

```cs
// Guard against Path Traversal Attacks:
var extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
if (!string.Equals(extension, ".pdf"))
    return BadRequest();

var extractedFileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
if (fileName != extractedFileName)
    return BadRequest();
```

Comment: Thanx dude for your revert